# Windows 10 UAC changing for one specific user

Tags: active-directory, uac, windows-10

I have one user who was recently upgraded to Windows 10 on a laptop that re-enters our domain every day. I have checked on the AD side and notice nothing restrictive about his permissions or which OUs that he belongs to. When he plugs back into the network in the morning, he is informed that his UAC permissions have changed. I have attempted to replicate this with various users who actually have more restrictive access than he does and am unable to replicate this. Has anyone seen or heard of this behaviour with Windows 10 yet? This ONLY happens to Windows 10 laptops that we've noticed (we have several Windows 7 laptops as well.)

Thank you.